# when using limit and offset in mysql for pagination, how can I tell this is last page or not?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

is there any built-in pre-defined mysql method to check if query result with limit offset is last page or not? I found some recommendation to utilize sql_calc_found_rows and found_rows(), but it requires two different query, although I need more simple and straightforward way.

Ultimately, I am using FastAPI and SqlAlchemy right now and I want something equivalent like spring data jpa, Pageable method "isFirst()" and "isLast()". Is there any elegant way to implement those two method using FastAPI and SqlAlchemy?

I know Flast-SqlAlchemy supports hasNext() boolean-returning method, but I guess vanilla SqlAlchemy does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trick I have used before is to get 1 more result than you need and just use it to determine if there is *more*.  You will not know the last page's offset but you will know if the current offset is the last page.

For example if your `page_count` is something like 10 results then send a limit of `11`.  Then if you get 10 or less results you know this is the last page but if you get 11 you know there is another page and you show 10 and throw away the 11th result.

**Python PSUEDO code**

```py
def get_page_of_results(current_offset, PAGE_COUNT=10):
    results = session.query(Result).offset(current_offset).limit(PAGE_COUNT + 1).all()
    return dict(
        is_first=current_offset == 0,
        is_last=len(results) < PAGE_COUNT,
        next_offset=current_offset + PAGE_COUNT,
        # Trim off last result
        results=results[:PAGE_COUNT])
```

The performance between 10 and 11 shouldn't be a big deal unless you are loading huge object trees or something.

Also this method is db agnostic.

Comment: Thx for your comment! What do you think of setting PAGE_COUNT to 100? will it affect some unexpected performance issue comparing to the pseudo code you shared?

Comment: Nothing unexpected other than just loading more things.  Usually the application side is more affected than the database with such small queries but I'd have to know more.  Probably doesn't matter either way at this point though.  Are you actually displaying 100 results at a time though ?

Comment: Im not sure actually. Currently Im working on api back side, not front side which shows result to users. @IanWilson

Comment: I guess inequality sign should be reversed

Comment: @ethany21 You are correct.  I updated it.  Thanks.